# IoT edge module fails to start on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, azure-iot-edge

I can't seem to be able to deploy a module that works on a stand alone deployment on a Kubernetes edge.
Is there anything special that needs to be done in the module?

Error thrown is as follows (thrown when trying to create hub client):

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:35001

at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {

errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',

code: 'ECONNREFUSED',

syscall: 'connect',

address: '127.0.0.1',

port: 35001

}
```

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please confirm the exact document you have followed for deploying IoT Edge module? Please look into this doc and see if it helps. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-edge-kubernetes

Comment: Are you able to resolve the issue? Did you get a chance to look at the above doc?